# User Roles and permission based access in node.js

Tags: node.js, authorization

I have developed app in Node.js. I am using Sequelize for MSSQL and I have created API’s I am consuming API's in Angular.

The thing that I want to know is about security: I have implemented JWT for authentication. Now I want to implement Roles right management my requirement is :

1. A user can have multiple Roles(admin, Master).
2. A Role can have
   multiple Permissions ( Create, Update, etc...).

So a user can have one or more the one role and, a role can have one or more the one permission. Permission is like, create a record, delete a record etc.
a user can access API's he has permissions of.

Is there any package of NPM or any other suggestion?

I have found this so far: user-groups-roles
https://www.npmjs.com/package/user-groups-roles

Answer (score 0):

You can just create new table in db for example 'user-roles', pass there roles you want and then just connect user with roles you want. Then on server you should create middlewares that check user have permissions to specific endpoint, if not throw 401/403.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to create the user models including roles.
userModel.js

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const validator=require('validator');
const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,'Please tell us your name ']
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,'Please provide your mail'],
        unique:true,
        lowercase:true,
        validate:[validator.isEmail,'Please provide valid email'],
    },
role:{
        type:String,
        enum:['user','guide','admin'],
        default:'user'
    },
})
const User=mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
module.exports=User;
```

you can use this code for your roles verify.
(authController.js)

```
exports.restictTo=(...roles)=>{
    return(req,res,next) =>{
        //role ['admin','guide'].role=user
      if(!roles.includes(req.user.role)){
          return next(consloe.log('You do not have permission to perform this action',403));
      }
      next();
    }
}
```

finally, you can call the restictTo function inside your route
authRoute.js

```
    const express=require('express');

    const authController=require('./../controllers/authController')
    const router=express.Router();
    router.route('/').get(authController.protect,authController.restictTo('admin'),userController.getalluser);
module.exports=router;
```